# How to create more than one reference to a table in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Let's say I have two tables:

`CREATE TABLE drinks (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT           AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name             VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  morning_drink_id INT,
  evening_drink_id INT
);`

How can I make those drink_id references valid?

I’ve tried:

- adding a view

  `CREATE VIEW morning_drinks AS SELECT * FROM drinks;
  CREATE VIEW evening_drinks AS SELECT * FROM drinks;`
- adding foreign keys

  `FOREIGN KEY morning_drink_key   (morning_drink_id)   REFERENCES drinks(id),
  FOREIGN KEY evening_drink_key   (evening_drink_id)   REFERENCES drinks(id)`

`bake` craches in both cases... Is there a proper way?

Comment: What version of Cakephp? You don't need to create the SQL views, nor _technically_ the foreign keys. You just need to create the correct **hasMany** and **belongsTo** entries in the models.

Comment: 3.0, foreign keys are mentioned in there [quick start guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html). So looks like I should add these relations after using bake.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Drink' => array(
        'className' => 'Drink',
        'foreignKey' => 'morning_drink_id'
    )
);
```

this you can add to Users model. And this is how to do it.

edit:

Bake is expecting tables for your two foreign keys, and it’s complaining about them. I got the same error as you when I deleted the ‘morning_drinks’ view, else it created all. Add those two views and try again.

Comment: with your help, bake will do it for you as well. what's the error bake is stopping with?

Comment: Here's the error:

``
$ bin/cake bake all users
Creating file ~/test/tests/TestCase/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php
Wrote `~/test/tests/TestCase/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php`
Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drinksdb.morning_drinks' doesn't exist in [~/test/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php, line 130]
2015-03-25 09:38:36 Error: [Cake\Database\Exception] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drinksdb.morning_drinks' doesn't exist
```